# What does it mean, if I got answer “Thank you for CV, but we just employed new colleague”?

Tags: job-search, applications

****Edited question****

I got following answer for my job application:

"Thank you for sending CV, but we just found new colleague."

If the company knew, that I am not suitable, why they waited to answer me after hiring of other person?

Or they found my CV after that hiring, even I sent CV 3 weeks ago?

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot read minds here. The only information they've given, is that you were not successful. I don't think there's much more insight we can give than you already have - it's not uncommon for hiring managers to be lacking, when it comes to feedback or reply times, so I'd recommend just moving onto the next opportunity.

Comment: The only thing you can know for sure, is that you didn't get the job.

Comment: @Bilkokuya edited question

Answer (score 18):

> Thank you for CV, but we just employed new colleague.

This most likely means your resume was received, but they have already filled the position.

Comment: Or that it was recieved prior to the decision process, but was considered to be too far down the stack of qualified applicants to warrant some kind of interview.

Comment: @Mister Positive I sent CV three weeks ago, before filling of position.

Comment: I'd say most likely that it means they simply weren't shortlisted. Either way, it's one of those "put to one side and move on" types of situations.